# How to reverse an active for loop when a condition is satisfied in python?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to work with for loop, and my requirement is to reverse the loop after some iterations. For example,

```
for i in range(10):
   print(i)
   if i==5:
      '''reverse loop iterating from 5 to 0'''
```

Is there a way to reverse the loop, or any other loop functions can do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you could take advantage of something like `for x,y in zip(range(10),range(10,0,-1)):` or find its difference with endpoint or something

Comment: Try `print(5 - abs(5 - i))`

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Thanks, but it seems like the two iterations runs at same time.

Comment: Yes both iteration start at the same time, if you dont want that, then use `10 - i`, that should return the _opposite_

Answer (score -1):

I guess that this could work as it reverse iterates as soon as the condition is satisfied

```
for i in range(10):
    if i<5:
        print(i)
    elif i==5:
        for j in range(5,0,-1):
            print(j)
    else:
        break
```

Hope it was helpful

Comment: What's the point of setting up the first loop from 0 to 9 if you know that you're going to break at 5? You could have simply written two loops: One from 0 to 5, and a second one from 5 to 0.

Comment: ya but i thought the condition satisfying was the whole point . For instance we can modify and use this code in many situations